# how to Echo $var as variable name and not value in php?

Tags: php

I have my line of code

```
textinjector("/var/www/html/uploadTest/test2.php", 26,  "'test' => array('$this', 'getTestData'),");
```

i need the $this variable to be printed as:
"$this"

and not as the value stored in $this.

my complete code:

```
$PageTitle = "shop";

$PageTitleCaps =  ucfirst($PageTitle); 
echo "Caps is $PageTitleCaps";
// this function injects the injTesxt into the line number in the document directory
function textinjector($file, $linerNumber, $injText ) {

$content = file($file); //Read the file into an array. Line number => line content
foreach($content as $lineNumber => &$lineContent) { //Loop through the array (the "lines")
    if($lineNumber == $linerNumber) { //Remember we start at line 0.
        $lineContent .= $injText . PHP_EOL; //Modify the line. (We're adding another line by using PHP_EOL)

    } 
}

$allContent = implode("", $content); //Put the array back into one string
file_put_contents($file, $allContent); //Overwrite the file with the new content
echo "$injText was injected to $file at line number $lineNumber";
}




textinjector("$fileDirectory", 26,  '"test" => array("$this", "getTestData"),');
```

Any sugestions?

Comment: why? `$this` is reserved in OOP. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: $this is a variable that will be injected to another document. so i need the variable name $this to be echoed out as is and not with the value

Comment: use another variable

Comment: No it needs to be $this. the file im injecting it into will detect the variable as $this from the reserved

Comment: your code looks ok to me, see if error reporting helps http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php other than that, I don't know what to say/do. Look at your html source and run a var  dump

Comment: Thank you for your help fred, I kno wthe code is working, I am trying to have the variable $this be echoed as is and not be detected as a variable.

Comment: You're welcome. Well, wait to see if someone else can help you here. I am obviously not grasping the question, *cheers*

Comment: Its ok. apreachieate your help

Comment: Your code __will__ print `$this` as string as your argument string is in single quotes, therefore it will not be parsed.

Comment: But in your first piece of code you pass argument in `"` quotes therefore `$this` value is parsed.

Comment: as tested even if i put '$this' for some reason this was too parsed. I ended finding that if i replace the variable since this variable is a reserved in OOP as fred ii mentioned after declaring a seperate variable it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found out how to do this on my own.

Just created a seperate variabele i.e. $thisVar

then added

```
$thisVar ='$this';

echo $thisVar;
```

will now echo

```
$this
```

yay.
Thank you to all thwe helpers out there.

AT